# Weighted multiple regression in R with prespecified weights

Tags: r, regression

I would like to run a regression of the following form:

```
Y ~ B1*predictor1 + B2*predictor2 + B3*predictor3
```

I would like to specify `B1,B2,B3` to hold the values: `0.4,0.2,0.1`

Is there way to weight these three predictors by the values of `B1,B2,B3` using lm?

So for example I would like to do:

```
lm(y ~ 0.4*predictor1 + 0.2*predictor2 + 0.1*predictor3)
```

I know there is the argument weights but that only seems to work with one predictor.

Comment: What would it mean, conceptually, to "weight" the predictors?  There's no way to make sense of this for ordinary least squares regression, so what kind of regression are you talking about?

Comment: I would like to specify the beta weights in the regression because I know the best linear combination of weights for the predictors.

Comment: Then there is no regression left to do apart from finding the constant term, which will be the mean of `y - 0.4*predictor1 - 0.2*predictor2 - 0.1*predictor3`.

Comment: I only want to do aregression to check whether it correctly predicts y when I use those weights.

Comment: If you just want the convenience of the `lm()` methods, you can feed your predictions into the `offset` argument.  Or in an `+offset()` entry in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you still want coefficients estimated on top of your weights, you can use the `I()` construct I believe.  So:

`lm(y~I(0.4*predictor1)+I(0.2*predictor2)+I(0.1*predictor3))`

This would really just scale the coefficients and not actually change any inferences.  It can make sense, though, to change age in years into age in decades at times.  It can make a real difference if you are ridging/penalizing the model at all.

Comment: what I would like to do is actually combine the predictors in the regression by giving them different weights. so I don't want to scale them but weight them

Comment: So something like `lm(y~I(0.4*predictor1+0.2*predictor2+0.1*predictor3))`