# Weighted multiple regression in R with different weights for each independent variable

Tags: r, regression, modeling

We are looking at how fast a healthcare team (physician-in-training, supervising physician, nurse) order antibiotics for severely ill patients and the relative contributions of each member to the ordering time.

In univariable regression, for example with the trainees, for each patient, we measured the impact of the trainee as follows:

- **Independent variable:** the mean ordering time for all other the other patients cared for by the trainee
- **Weighting:** 1 / standard error for all of the times of the trainees

Seems to work great and 72% of the variation in ordering times was due to the trainee with a much smaller amount due to the supervisor and the nurse.

**Question**: how can I test for independent contributions in multivariable analysis? Problem is that each independent (trainee, supervisor, nurse) has a different weight (1/SE of trainee, 1/SE of supervisor, 1/SE of nurse).

Based on [Weighted multiple regression in R with prespecified weights](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59020/weighted-multiple-regression-in-r-with-prespecified-weights#comment113296_59020) , I tried:

```r
    lm(y ~ I(predictor1/SE.Predictor1) + I(predictor2/SE.Predictor2) + 
             I(predictor3/SE.Predictor3))
```

But that does not seem to make sense here.

Comment: I'm thinking this is really a mixed models question. Presumably the trainees are grouped within individual supervisors and individual nurses. This is better handled in a forum where such discussions are encouraged, but they are not encouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: The `weights=` argument in `lm` applies to observations not the independent variables so a different regression model is probably called for.

Comment: I think I may have an answer. Your suggestion about a different model led me to look at using a second regression using nurses with their own weights, to predict the residuals of the first regression (ordering times by the trainees using the trainees' own weights). Helpful to read was the course at https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/node/666 .

The resulting answer seems sensible, the nurses times were significantly associated with the residents' residuals whereas the supervisors' times were not.

Comment: Trying out different approaches and sticking to the one with the "seemingly best" results is not good statistical practice (-> confirmation bias). I would rather suggest discussing the matter with a professional statistician.